# How to implement JPQL query?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpql

I have working query in PostgreSQL:

```
select s.id, s.seat_number as available_seat, s.row_number as available_row, rm.room_name as screening_room
from seats s
         join rooms rm on rm.id=s.room_id
         left join (
    select r.seat_id from reserved_seats r
                              join reservations  res on res.id=r.reservation_id AND res.screening_id = 3 ) res on res.seat_id=s.id
where res.seat_id is null AND s.room_id=3
ORDER BY s.id;
```

But I make mistakes translating it into the JPA query language.

[image]

Can I use nested SELECTs in JPQL?

**The answer is to use native query**:

```
@Query(value =
            "SELECT s.id seatId, s.seat_number availableSeat, " +
                    "s.row_number availableRow, rm.name screeningRoom \n" +
                    "FROM seats s\n" +
                    "JOIN rooms rm on rm.id=s.room_id\n" +
                    "   LEFT JOIN (\n" +
                    "       SELECT r.seat_id FROM reserved_seats r\n" +
                    "       JOIN reservations res ON res.id=r.reservation_id " +
                    "       AND res.screening_id = :screeningId) res ON res.seat_id=s.id\n" +
                    "WHERE res.seat_id IS NULL AND s.room_id=:roomId AND s.row_number=:rowNumber\n" +
                    "ORDER BY s.id;", nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: Read about jpql. Ist is different from sql.

Comment: It works on objects not on tables.

Comment: Don't put unnecessary images in questions. Your copy paste works on text too.

Comment: @Kayaman it for showing my error...

Comment: @Jens read my query, its on objects

Comment: Check your spaces.

Comment: @andrew17 working on object looks like: *from seats s
         join s.room*. BTW i am not sure if subselects are supported by jpql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The answer is to use native query**:

```
@Query(value =
            "SELECT s.id seatId, s.seat_number availableSeat, " +
                    "s.row_number availableRow, rm.name screeningRoom \n" +
                    "FROM seats s\n" +
                    "JOIN rooms rm on rm.id=s.room_id\n" +
                    "   LEFT JOIN (\n" +
                    "       SELECT r.seat_id FROM reserved_seats r\n" +
                    "       JOIN reservations res ON res.id=r.reservation_id " +
                    "       AND res.screening_id = :screeningId) res ON res.seat_id=s.id\n" +
                    "WHERE res.seat_id IS NULL AND s.room_id=:roomId AND s.row_number=:rowNumber\n" +
                    "ORDER BY s.id;", nativeQuery = true)
```